# Exception while adding migrations: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.1.4.0,

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to add initial migrations to my project that is using EF Core + PostGRE SQL Driver

My project structure looks like:

```
.sln
|--
    |
    |-- Context(cslib)
    |-- Controllers(cslib)
    |-- AppRunner(console app), Startup
    |--(...)
```

Where AppRunner has:

> PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="2.1.2"

Context has:

> PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.1"

Controllers have:

> PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.1"

My Startup:

```
services
    .AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
    .AddDbContext<Context>
    (
        o => o
        .UseNpgsql(DbConnectionString)
    )
    .BuildServiceProvider();
```

And everything works fine - app works correctly, but when I want to perform

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```

in AppRunner folder it throws

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor..ctor(Object reportHandler, IDictionary args)
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
>          at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>          at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.ReflectionOperationExecutor..ctor(String assembly, String startupAssembly, String projectDir, String dataDirectory, String rootNamespace, String language)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.ProjectCommandBase.CreateExecutor()
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.MigrationsAddCommand.Execute()
>          at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
>       Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Anybody has an idea what can cause that?

Comment: Well, the error message is saying it can't load Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version= **2.1.4.0** and you have installed "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="**2.1.1**" ..?

Comment: .. and the [release notes for PostgreSQL 2.1.2](https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/releases/tag/v2.1.2) say _"This release depends on EF Core 2.1.2"_